# C# FileCreationTime

Tags: c#-4.0, fileinfo

I have the below module which is part of a larger program for searching the text within DOCX files. This is the code for when the search button is clicked;

```
      {
        this.resultListView.Items.Clear();

        try
        {
            foreach (var filePath in Search(this.txtDirectory.Text, this.txtSearch.Text, this.cBoxUseSubdirectories.Checked, this.cBoxCaseSensitive.Checked, this.rBtnRegex.Checked))
            {
                var file = new FileInfo(filePath);


                this.resultListView.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(new string[] { file.Name, string.Format("{0:0.0}", file.Length / 1024d), file.FullName}));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(this, string.Format("Exception details:\n{0}", ex), string.Format("Exception '{0}' occurred.", ex.GetType()), MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

This is the code for the Search method which is called with the arguments above;

```
 private static IEnumerable<string> Search(string directory, string    searchString, bool searchSubdirectories, bool caseSensitive, bool useRegex)
{
    var isMatch = useRegex ? new Predicate<string>(x => Regex.IsMatch(x, searchString, caseSensitive ? RegexOptions.None : RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
        : new Predicate<string>(x => x.IndexOf(searchString, caseSensitive ? StringComparison.Ordinal : StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0);

    foreach (var filePath in Directory.GetFiles(directory, "*.docx", searchSubdirectories ? SearchOption.AllDirectories : SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly))
    {
        string docxText;

        using (var stream = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
            docxText = new DocxToStringConverter(stream).Convert();

        if (isMatch(docxText))
            yield return filePath;
    }
}
```

There are other classes which I do not think are relevant here.

the results are populated in a listview via this;

```
 this.resultListView.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(new string[] { file.Name, string.Format("{0:0.0}", file.Length / 1024d), file.FullName}));
            }
```

I want to add an extra column to show the file creation date for the found files. I tried adding this;

```
  var fileCreatedDate  = File.GetCreationTime(filePath);
```

then adding file.fileCreatedDate to the this.resultListView.Items.Add but it didn't work.

Any suggestions on how to pull the file created date out of the existing code?

Answer (score 0):

Return an IEnumerable of Tuple instances.

```
private static IEnumerable<Tuple<string, DateTime>> Search(string directory, string    searchString, bool searchSubdirectories, bool caseSensitive, bool useRegex)
{
    var isMatch = useRegex ? new Predicate<string>(x => Regex.IsMatch(x, searchString, caseSensitive ? RegexOptions.None : RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
        : new Predicate<string>(x => x.IndexOf(searchString, caseSensitive ? StringComparison.Ordinal : StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0);

    foreach (var filePath in Directory.GetFiles(directory, "*.docx", searchSubdirectories ? SearchOption.AllDirectories : SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly))
    {
        string docxText;

        using (var stream = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
            docxText = new DocxToStringConverter(stream).Convert();

        if (isMatch(docxText))
            yield return new Tuple<string, DateTime>(filePath, System.IO.File.GetLastWriteTime(filePath));
    }
}
```

Tuple will have two properties: Item1, and Item2.  Item1 is the path, and Item2 is the date.

You could also use your own class in place of the Tuple, but the Tuple was simple to code.

Comment: with that I am getting an error; 'Cannot implicitly convert type System.Tuple<string, DateTime> to type 'string'?

Answer (score 0):

Through some trial and error I managed to sort the problem.

I added this to the initial button click code;

```
    var fileCreatedDate  = File.GetCreationTime(filePath);
```

and then this;

```
      this.resultListView.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(new string[] {  file.Name, string.Format("{0:0.0}", file.Length / 1024d), file.FullName, fileCreatedDate.ToString()}));
```

the fileCreated.ToString() sorts it.